# same data is showing multiple times in hql

Tags: hibernate, orm, hql

I am using following method to fetch data from database. It is fetching data properly from database. Here `bd.billProductList` can contain one or more product.
Problem is if there is only one product means `bd.billProductList` size is one then `obj` size is one. If `bd.billProductList` size is 5 then  `obj` size is five.
I am iterating it in jsp page.
 `obj` is showing same data multiple time if `bd.billProductList` is more than 1

```
public List<BillDetails> fetch(long id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List<BillDetails> obj = null;
        try {
            String hql = "from BillDetails as bd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.billProductList as bpd "
                    + "left join fetch bpd.productDetails as pd "
                    + "left join fetch pd.sizes "
                    + "left join fetch pd.colors "
                    + "left join fetch pd.productTypes "
                    + "left join fetch pd.productModelDetails "
                    + "where bd.billNo=:id ";


            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("id", id);
            obj = query.list();
            tx.commit();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Size is "+obj.size());
        return obj;
    }
```

How to resolve this

Comment: Don't join fetch multiple list, it leads to Cartesian product.

Comment: what should i use then?

Comment: Don't join more than one collection, you just can join many ManyToOne or OneToOne. For another collections use @ BatchSize or @ Subselect, I recommend to use @BatchSize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, you need DISTINCT:

```
String hql = "select distinct bd from BillDetails as bd "
                + "left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd "
                + "left join fetch bd.billProductList as bpd "
                + "left join fetch bpd.productDetails as pd "
                + "left join fetch pd.sizes "
                + "left join fetch pd.colors "
                + "left join fetch pd.productTypes "
                + "left join fetch pd.productModelDetails "
                + "where bd.billNo=:id ";
```